# Dynamically switch Firebase Reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

the code below is suppose to change my database reference depending on my userlvlid however whenever I run the activity which contains this part, the app crashes i do not understand why I cant change my "ref" anymore.

```
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
                        ref.child(uid).child("userlvlid").addValueEventListener(
                                new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                         userlvlid = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                                        if(userlvlid.compareTo("1")==0){
                                            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this,userlvlid,
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("bystander");
                                        }
                                        else if(userlvlid.compareTo("2")==0){
                                            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this,userlvlid,
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("firstaider");
                                        }
                                        else if(userlvlid.compareTo("3")==0){
                                            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this,userlvlid,
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ambulance");
                                        }
                                        else{
                                         //do nothing
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                }
                        );
```

ERROR REPORT:
[image]

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: You should post the text of the error so we can read and search it , not an image, please

Comment: Also, that logcat says nothing about why your app crashes. And there are no errors there.

Comment: thats the last thing i could see in my logcat

Comment: when I dont place the lines with the ref it doesnt crash

Comment: i have been trying to look for the error as well but it doesnt say any it just crashes thats why I posted that pic

Comment: I find it weird for it to crash because I was able to change my reference outside that if-else statement